# How to iterate through all registered classes in the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

Is there a way to iterate through the registered classes (`struct class`) in the kernel? I would like to check if a class with a particular name already exists, and if so, retrieve a pointer to the class.

Comment: Class as in device class i.e. `struct class`?

Comment: As far as I understand, a device **class** is not something intended to be used outside of the device. That is, if you have a pointer to a device, you could obtain its class. Otherwise one shouldn't be interested about a particular class and about the pointer to that class.

Comment: If you want to add a device to a device class, you would need to register the device (and possibly its driver) with the subsystem that controls the device class using functions provided by the subsystem code.